# Proper way to return an array

Tags: cocoa, methods, nsmutablearray, return-value, return

I never seem to get this right.  I've got a method that returns a mutable array.  What is the proper way to return the array and avoid potential memory leaks?

If I plan to store the results locally inside another view controller, does that affect the way the array should be returned?

Lastly, what if it's just an non-mutable array?  Does that require a different technique?

thanks,
Howie

Comment: The whole point of all these great answers is that, from the calling method, if you don't `alloc` you don't have to `release` meaning that it MUST be autoreleased. Wanted to leave this link too http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment: yar: That's a bit misleading, as it implies that you have to `autorelease` it, but autoreleasing is effectively the same as releasing (since that's what it does, just not immediately). What you meant is that an object created by a method without `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` in its selector is already autoreleased, so you can just return that.

Comment: @Peter Hosey, that is what I meant, did NOT mean to imply you would have to autorelease it yourself. I meant that the called method... well, you know what I meant, your comment is clearer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your method does not have alloc or copy in the name then the proper thing is to return a autoreleased version of the array. Also, you should return a copy of the array to prevent modifications to your local copy

```
- (NSMutabalArray*] mutableArray {
    return [[myArray mutableCopy] autorelease];
}

- (NSArray*] array {
    return [[myArray copy] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is normally true for any container class that your should return either a copy of mutableCopy of it, if you need prevent changes made to the returned copy from affecting the instance you have inside your class. Granted the copying mechanism is not need if the container is created inside the method solely for returning, in this case you don't need to worry about the copy.

Comment: I'll point out for other readers that you normally should not name a method `getFoo`, as the “get” prefix in Cocoa style indicates a method that returns a value by reference (as NSColor's `getRed:green:blue:alpha:`, which takes four pointers to CGColor variables into which you want it to put the component values). See http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html and http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/AccessorConventions.html .

Comment: @Peter. Of Course. No idea what I was thinking on that. Too much java work recently. Fixing it now.

Answer (score 2):

Return an auto-released object. If you've created your array with any alloc/init/copy methods - you should send autorelease message to array before returning it (something like `return [myArray autorelease];`). Otherwise arrays created with factory methods (`arrayFrom...` `arrayWithContentsOf...`) return autoreleased object so you don't need to worry about memory leaks there.

You should read about memory management and retain count on apple dev site. There might be some other initialization methods that retain returned object which would 'cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

For a NSMutableArray I would use:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getMyArray
{
   NSMutableArray *retval = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   // do your stuff w/ array
   return [retval autorelease];
}
```

The caller of this code may want to `retain` the returned array, since it is autoreleased.

Comment: As an NSMutableArray* is being returned, I'd recommend calling `copy` on the the returned object unless you want the array to be able to changed underneath you.

Comment: thanks - what is the difference if I retain the returned array or dont retain it?  It is just a matter of what I intend to do with it so that if I might need it later I should retain it?

Comment: You only need to `retain` it if you want to hold on to it once the calling method ends. Otherwise, you have the `autoreleased` object until your method exits.

Comment: I've clarified the final paragraph, as the previous version implied (to me, at least) that `getMyArray` might want to retain it. This method should not; its caller may want to, and I think that's what Pablo meant.

Comment: @Ward: If you retain it and the array changes (becuase it's mutable) then the version you've retained also changes (it's just a pointer, after all) This means that you could have a property changing without you knowing about it. That's fine if you want it to do that. But sometimes you just want a copy of the array as it was at the time that you answered it, so a copy might be a better choice.

This is the same reasoning behind declaring array properties as `@property (copy) NSArray *anArray;`

Comment: Abizern: See the edit list for this answer. The final paragraph in the previous version is what Ward was asking about.